# Add external data source in End User Report Designer DevExpress

Tags: devexpress, devextreme, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-mvc, devextreme-angular

Can we add external data source in End User Report Designer rather than giving in web.config file.
I just need to add new external data source like in form of popup that will take SQL server path ,username and password

Answer (score 0):

To add custom data sources into the report designer, create these data sources at runtime and add them to the [ASPxReportDesigner.DataSources](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.ASPxReportDesigner.DataSources) collection.
Take a look at the [Web Report Designer - How to add/edit/remove data sources in the web report designer (Custom DataSource wizard)](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/Reporting_web-report-designer-how-to-add-edit-remove-datasourses-in-the-web-report-designer-t196136) еxample which demonstrates this approach in action.

Comment: But this is not taking new data source.Its just editing the data source.I need a wizard, so i can pass SQL credentials.By this way a new data source will be added.Any wizard for SQL credentials?